# How i delete name of one image from name of images in array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, delete-row

I have a  Multiple images in array in row like:

```
["1.jpg","2.jpg"]
```

I need delete name of one image from name of images in array in db,
this is my form to show and delete submit:

```
@foreach(json_decode($post->images ,true) as $images)
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
    <div class="portfolio-box">
        <img src="public/img/offers/{{ $images }}" class="img-responsive"alt="">
        <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                <form action="images/{{ $images }}/delete" method="get">

                    {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

and this is my Route:

```
    Route::get('images/{images}/delete','DashboardController@deleteimg');
```

what i do in Controller ??

Comment: You have a table `posts` and this table has  column `images` with json decoded array of image names. And you want to delete image for some post by name from this array. Right?

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass post id in form

```
@foreach(json_decode($post->images ,true) as $images)
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
   <div class="portfolio-box">
    <img src="public/img/offers/{{ $images }}" class="img-responsive"alt="">
    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
            <form action="images/{{ $images }}/delete" method="get">

                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <input type="hidden"  name="post_id" value="{{$post->id}}"/>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">

            </form>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

And in controller

```
public function deleteimg($image,Request $req){
   $post=Post::find($req['post_id']);
   $images=json_decode($post->images);
   $_image=[];
   $_image[]=$image;
   $post->images=json_encode(array_values(array_diff($images,$_image)));
   $post->save();
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

OR

```
public function deleteimg($image,Request $req){
   $post=Post::find($req['post_id']);
   $images=json_decode($post->images);
   unset($images[$image]);
   $post->images=json_encode(array_values(images));
   $post->save();
   return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: not working, the error is `ErrorException in DashboardController.php line71:array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array`

Comment: Good, it's Working, Thank You

Comment: I have a new problem !!!!!! i try to delete a one more image, it's say: `ErrorException in DashboardController.php line 73:
array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array` and i looking to db `{"0":"1.jpg","1":"2.jpg"}`

Comment: what does it says?

Comment: Ok issue was array_diff map items into key value so you have array_values before saving..Check updated answer

Comment: Ahaa, Now working, Thank you very much @Lakshay Jain